# How to make Xcode 4.1 fullscreen feature use external display too?

Tags: xcode4

I have an external display connected to my MBP, and would like to use the MBP display to display (fullscreen) Xcode project and display the Organizer/documentation on the external display?

If anyone has filed a bug report.feature request, please share the radar number and I'll file and reference it. Thanks.

[Edit: I am aware of the swipe left-right gestures to do this, but the external display is blank (well, actually displaying a gray background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Closing question] Read the Xcode documentation for full-screen mode. From that and reading Joshua's comment, left with impression intent was primarily to support single-display, not displaying Xcode project fullscreen on one display with documentation (also fullscreen but) on a separate display.

Answer (score 1):

The release notes specifically say a full-screen app's main full-screen window is always on the main display (the one that hosts the menu bar). Other screens are left for auxilliary windows. This is done for reasons of simplification for users. In other words, it's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I must be doing something wrong. My stock Xcode 4.1 (i.e. no changes to behavior) display the project on main display fine, but shows an empty (no auxiliary windows) gray external monitor. Appreciate any tips, thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the new full screen mode? I don't believe auxiliary windows will just automatically participate in full-screen. You likely have to do more work. Read the docs and post the code you're using.